# SQL two SELECTS multiple and two JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables

```
tblmodel
id  modelname
1   model1
2   model2
3   model3
4   model4
5   model5

tblbrand
id  brandname
1   brand1
2   brand2
3   brand3
4   brand4
5   brand5

tblvehicles (vehiclemodel and vehiclebrand are "IDs" from tblbrand and tblmodel)
id  vehiclemodel  vehiclebrand
1   1             4
2   3             3
3   5             2
4   5             4
5   2             2
```

I want to select brand ID & brand name AS "bid" then join tblbrand on tblbrand(id)=tblvehicle(vehiclebrand)

AND

model ID & model name AS "mid" then join tblmodel on tblmodel(id)=tblvehicle(vehiclemodel)

WHERE tblvehicles(id)=:id

here is my SQL code:

```
"
SELECT v.*
     , m.ModelName
     , m.id as mid
     , b.BrandName
     , b.id as bid 
  from tblvehicles v
  join tblmodel m
   on m.id = v.VehicleModel 
  join tblbrand b
   on b.id = v.VehiclesBrand 
 where v.id=:id
";
```

> I have two dropdown/select (one is model and the other is brand), but
>   whenever I try to edit them (ex: model1 -> model4 or brand3 ->
>   brand2), they will end up overwriting each other for example if i
>   change model1 -> model4, my brand3 becomes -> model4 as well.

Here is my PHP/HTML code for the select/dropdown

MODEL:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="modelname" required>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->mid);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($mdname=$result->ModelName); ?> </option>
        <?php 
            $ret="select id, ModelName from tblmodel";
            $query= $dbh -> prepare($ret);
            $query-> execute();
            $resultss = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if($query -> rowCount() > 0){
                    foreach($resultss as $results){
                if($results->ModelName==$mdname){
                    continue;
            } else{
        ?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($results->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($results->ModelName);?></option>
<?php }}} ?>
</select>
```

BRAND

```
    <select class="selectpicker" name="brandname" required>
        <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->bid);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($bdname=$result->BrandName); ?> </option>
            <?php 
                $ret="select id, BrandName from tblbrand";
                $query= $dbh -> prepare($ret);
                $query-> execute();
                $resultss = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    if($query -> rowCount() > 0){
                        foreach($resultss as $results){
                    if($results->BrandName==$bdname){
                        continue;
                } else{
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($results->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($results->BrandName);?></option>
    <?php }}} ?>
    </select>
```

> Can someone help me what's wrong with the SQL code that causes it to overwrite? Or is the structure itself wrong?
>
> **> UPDATE: Actually it works on the server side. When I check the database, it gets the correct id that I select for each in BrandName and ModelName.  but when I throw it back to the client side, the data that appears on the "Select" is wrong. modelname becomes brand1. It's getting the id of brandname.**

Comment: Okay. And what's the question?

Comment: @Rahul sorry I already edited and added the question. Is the join or SQL structure wrong? hence why it overwrites?

Comment: I do not understand. Does your SQL Query give you the result you want ?I have made a small simulation here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb221d/4

Comment: I wouldn't do this, I'd run two queries

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually it works on the server side. When I check the database, it gets the correct id that I select for each in BrandName and ModelName.  but when I throw it back to the client side, the data that appears on the "Select" is wrong. modelname becomes brand1. It's getting the id from brandname.

Comment: Indeed, but what I meant was, I would select all the brands only and ask the user to pick one, then I would take what they picked and select only the models of the brand and I would then present that to the user. That's two queries no matter how it's cut (get all brands, get all models) unless you want to make it one query, in which case I would union rather than join and have a column to specify if it was a brand or model. The front end would have to split the results into two combo boxes and do the model filtering itself after a brand was chosen